# Error exporting an extremely simple Excel with Axlsx-Rails Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, rubygems, axlsx

I'm trying to export a simple Excel with a customers list using Axlsx-Rails gem:

```
  # Customers Controller
  def download
      @customers = Customer.all
      respond_to do |format|
        render xlsx: 'customers.xlsx.axlsx'
        # render xlsx: 'customers' TRYED BOTH
      end
  end

  # Template
  wb = xlsx_package.workbook
  wb.add_worksheet(name: "Download") do |sheet|
    @customers.each do |customer|
      sheet.add_row [customer.name, customer.email, customer.phone]
    end
  end
```

The template path is `views/customers/customers.xlsx.axlsx` and the error is `Missing template customers/customers`

Where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by replacing this:

```
respond_to do |format|
   render xlsx: 'customers.xlsx.axlsx'
end
```

with this:

```
render xlsx: "customers.xlsx"
```

Comment: I don't believe the trailing `.xlsx` is necessary either.